# Describing the clopen sets of a profinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups

I've read somewhere that *all* clopen subsets of a profinite group $$G \simeq \varprojlim\left(G_i, f_{ij}:G_i \to G_j\right)_{i,j \in I}$$ are exactly the preimages of subsets of the $G_i$'s. It's easy to see that subsets of $G$ of the latter form are clopen. But I'm not so sure about the other direction.

So my question is: is the above description of the clopen sets of $G$ true? If so, how? And if not, what's the best we can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Let me call a subset of $G$ *good* if it is the preimage of a subset of $G_i$ for some $i$.  First, note that the good sets are closed under finite unions and intersections: if $U$ the preimage of a subset of $G_i$ and $V$ is the preimage of a subset of $G_j$, then $U\cap V$ and $U\cup V$ are preimages of subsets of any $G_k$ that maps to both $G_i$ and $G_j$ in the inverse system.  Now by definition, the good sets form a subbasis for the topology on $G$.  Since they are closed under finite intersections, actually the good sets form a basis.  Thus any clopen set is a union of good sets.  But a clopen set is compact, so it is actually a finite union of good sets, and hence is itself good.

Comment: > $G_i \times G_j$

Is it true that an inverse system of finite groups is closed under finite products?

Comment: Er, I had in mind that the inverse system was the system of _all_ continuous homomorphisms from $G$ to finite groups.  If you have some particular fixed inverse system, you can instead just use any $G_k$ that maps to both $G_i$ and $G_j$ in the inverse system.

Comment: I see; that makes perfect sense.